# Showing trajectories are orthogonal

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

One is asked to show that $r^n = \alpha \sec (n\theta)$ and $r^n = \beta \csc (n\theta)$ are orthogonal trajectories. I'm familiar with a definition of an orthogonal trajectory, but... How exactly would you tackle this problem? I could try to caculate $n$-th derivative of $r$, but I see $n$-th derivative of $\sec x$ as a problem. There's a hint to this exercise, which states that $z^n = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ might be helpful, but I don't quite feel it. I'd greatly appreciate your help (some additional hints?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite as $$r^n\cos(n\theta)=\alpha,$$ $$r^n\sin(n\theta)=\beta,$$

That is $$z^n=\alpha+i\beta.$$

Now I think you know that if $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic, away from the zeroes of $f$ the contours on which $u$ and $v$ are constant cross at right angles. To prove this is just Cauchy-Riemann.

Answer (score 1):

As given by Sonner, also these are real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic complex variable function, satisfying CR relations. They are orthogonal trajectories representing lines of irrotational flow & force/stream functions & equi-potentials in electrostatics fluid mechanics respy.Also known as McLauren loci.